# How to add a message to validates in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form with a text field which needs to be a number and 5 or above.

**Issue:** I can't seem to get a message to appear when it's not validated

**I have tried:**

```
validates :price, :numericality => {:only_integer => true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 5, message: "should happen once per year" }
```

**And this** (I know this isn't a min number but just testing the message feature I saw on another post ... still no message if i use non-integer charecters.

```
 validates :price, format: { with: /\A\d+\z/, message: "Integer only. No sign allowed." }
```

**The main layout has:**

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
      <div class="alert alert-<%= name.to_s == 'notice' ? 'success' : 'danger' %> alert-dismissable">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

How can I have it so when the field entry isn't valid, it has a message appear?

**SOLVED:** kinda...

Just needed to add:

```
<% if @listing_video.errors.any? %>
    <ul>
      <% @listing_video.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <%= msg %>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
    <% end %>
```

To my form.

It doesn't pop up like a banner atm but will figure that out soon with bootstrap and/or css

I usually remove this from my forms to avoid the "double" error message situation but this is a case where it is needed.  I should had realized this before asking -

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If you have solved your own problem you can answer your own question. Don't do this by editing the question as it breaks the Q&A format of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

Just needed to add:

```
<% if @listing_video.errors.any? %>
    <ul>
      <% @listing_video.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <%= msg %>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
    <% end %>
```

To my form.

This creates an error for the validates above the input text field - which is what i want.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. A simple check for an amount

```
validate :amount_valid?

 def amount_valid?
  errors.add(:amount, "cant be zero") if self.amount.zero?
  errors.add(:amount, "cant be negative") if self.amount.negative?
end
```

display errors on UI after validations if errors present :)